# Comment tracer la ligne pour ce qui est accepté comme langage? Shouldn't we be trying to teach "proper" French language?

Tags: discussion

Ce site est encore en phase beta, aussi je me permets de poser cette question au sens large; de poser une question par rapport à la définition même de ce qu'est french.stackexchange.com.

En lisant les réponses sur les quelques premières questions de la page d'accueil, je m'aperçois que la position généralement acceptée est que si une expression est du langage populaire, elle est valide en tant que réponse à quelqu'un qui désire apprendre le Français.

Au sens large, ce site ne pourrait-il pas plutôt tenter d'offrir la référence actuelle, acceptée internationalement, plutôt que des expressions qui dépendent largement de la localisation de la personne qui réponds?

Par exemple, le mot cucul (offert en traduction à cheesy) qui, damnation, semble être maintenant inscrit dans les sites en lignes (au moins, ils ont la décence d'inscrire "familier"). Je trouve terrible qu'on apprenne aux gens à utiliser des termes du genre plutôt qu'une expression valide ("à l'eau de rose" ou "exagéré" sont déjà beaucoup mieux).

Qu'en pensez-vous? Suis-je vieux jeu? Trop conservateur? Je trouverais sincèrement dommage, dans 10 ans, de voir ces expressions familières entrer dans le dictionnaire à proprement parler. Comment tracer une limite? "Des chevals" est utilisé régulièrement, est-ce qu'on devrait pour autant l'accepter et l'enseigner aux apprenants?

---

This site is in beta phase, so I'll ask this in a larger scope; I'll ask about the very definition of this site's goal.

While reading some answers on the front page, I realize the accepted stance is that if an expression is of the familiar language, it is a valid answer to give to someone who's trying to learn French.

Couldn't this site be used to teach an internationally recognized reference, instead of localized opinions and terms of what can be used to mean something?

For instance, the word "cucul" (given as translation for cheesy) which, seven hells, is now included in online reference (which have the decency of defining as "familiar"). I find it is terrible to teach people these terms instead of a valid expression ("à l'eau de rose" or "exagéré" would be much better)

What do you think? Am I old fashioned? Too conservative? I'd be sad if in 10 years all these expressions would be part of the dictionary itself. How to draw the line? "Des chevals" is often used, should we accept it and teach it to learners?

Comment: Une américaine avec des connaissances très rudimentaires du français fut ma collègue. Une fois que je lui proposais de goûter un met quelconque, elle me dit qu'elle «est plein». Je lui explique qu'elle est pleine, parce qu'elle est femme, et que moi, je pourrais être plein. Un autre collègue saute au plafond, affirme qu'on ne doit pas lui enseigner ce genre de langage et propose un plus sophistiqué «Je suis rassasiée». Je ne peux, même 3 ans plus tard, imaginer qu'un niveau de langue aussi soutenu était approprié: il n'eût servi qu'à la mettre à part dans une société qui n'est pas si raffinée.

Comment: "Elle est pleine" est la manière dont on désigne une femelle animale qui attend des petits. On ne peut donc pas recommander à une femme de dire "je suis pleine". Si "je suis rassasiée" est trop soutenu pour vous, je vous propose "je n'ai plus faim"...

Comment: @Distic C'est très culturel comme expression, je ne crois pas qu'il y ait vraiment de ligne commune au Français sur Terre. C'est extrêmement courant où je suis de l'utiliser, peu importe le sexe de la personne. "Plein" n'a aucune connotation de gestation (ni par rapport à l'extomac en fait). "Plein" désigne simplement un récipient qui ne peut pas contenir plus, pas plus une femelle animale qu'un estomac. Pour être franc, je n'ai pas une seule fois entendu "elle est pleine" pour désigner une femelle animale, cela doit être une expression propre à votre région.

Comment: Cet usage est attesté par [le TLF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?11;s=3910584120;r=1;nat=;sol=0;), donc je ne pense pas qu'il s'agisse d'un régionalisme. Quand bien même ça ne serait plus tellement utilisé, il me semble qu'on ne peut pas vraiment recommander à une femme de dire "je suis pleine" pour dire qu'elle n'a plus faim.

Comment: Héhé, je ne comprends pas votre réticence. Simplement parce qu'une expression a un sens précis dans un cas particulier ne veut pas dire que les autres sens de cette expression en sont influencés. Vous semblez croire que d'utiliser "elle est pleine" avec une femme serait de la comparer à un animal? Respectueusement, cela me semble... ténu comme lien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

French.SE est un site ouvert à toute personne intéressée par le français, que sa langue maternelle soit le français ou toute autre langue.

Ce n'est pas un site d'enseignement, et encore moins un site limité à une forme de français ou une autre. Toutes les questions relatives à la langue française, son histoire, ses variantes, ses registres, ses expressions, ses difficultés, sa prononciation, etc. sont bienvenues; et toutes les réponses qui apparaissent pertinentes à leurs auteurs sont tout autant bienvenues.

Si quelqu'un souhaite apporter une réponse qui satisfait à ses propres critères tels que par exemple « *offrir la référence actuelle, acceptée internationalement, plutôt que des expressions qui dépendent largement de la localisation de la personne qui répond* », c'est très bien mais chacun est libre d'apporter d'autres réponses avec d'autres critères.

Il faut rester ouvert. Grandes sont les variétés d'ages, de culture et d'expertise entre les membres de FSE. Il ne faut donc pas s'attendre à des opinions homogènes. Par exemple Simon Deschamps considère comme moi que « mièvre » que je propose comme traduction possible de *cheesy* est d'un registre soutenu, mais Shautieh pense l'inverse.

Le système de votes et d'acceptation de la « meilleure » réponse par l'auteur de la question est certes discutable. On peut même dire, pour paraphraser Churchill, que c'est le pire des systèmes de gouvernance ... à l'exclusion de tous les autres.

Pour ce qui est de « cucul », je trouve qu'il s'agit d'une très bonne proposition. Ce mot correspond bien à ce qui peut encore être dit aujourd'hui en France dans un registre familier et on aurait pu d'ailleurs aussi ajouter l'imagé « cucul la praline ». Il est fort possible que « cucul » qui n'est pas  vraiment vulgaire en France soit perçu comme très déplacé au Québec ou ailleurs. Si c'est le cas, le mieux est d'apporter cette information comme commentaire à la réponse. Une critique constructive est souvent avantageuse pour tout le monde, c'est une *win-win situation* alors qu'un rejet et/ou un vote négatif est au contraire souvent source de frustration pour les deux parties.

Comment: Win-win! Anglicisme! ;-)

Comment: :) très nuancé, matière à réflexion! Merci.

Comment: @Frank non *win-win* est en italiques, donc en anglais dans le texte ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre - il faut dire _gagnant-gagnant_ ;-)

Comment: @Frank Que nenni, c'eût été un pléonasme après « avantageuse pour tout le monde » !

Comment: Tiens, vous avez donc en fait utilisé un pléonasme inter-lingual: vous avez paraphrasé en anglais ce que vous avez dit juste avant en français :-) Une figure de style moderne _frowned upon_ par l'Académie, sans nul doute ;-)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - on a un cas dans la discussion sur les marques diacritiques: une des réponses commet l'erreur de dire qu'omettre les accents sur les majuscules est acceptable, ce qui n'est pas vrai. Ceci a été repris en note par jlliagre, mais je serais d'avis que la correction n'est pas assez forte, et qu'il faudrait peut-être aller dans la réponse pour rayer l'affirmation erronée. Si l'on accepte que l'Académie est la garante du français correct. En fait, une réponse correcte devrait noter l'usage "abusif" et citer la position de l'Académie.

Comment: @Frank Une question ou une réponse peut être directement modifiée  par un tiers s'il s'agit d'une coquille ou toute erreur de typographie mais qui concerne uniquement la forme. Quand il s'agit du fond, l'usage et la courtoisie recommandent plutôt de signaler à l'auteur le point en question. Libre à lui d'en tenir compte ou pas, ou de proposer que sa réponse soit modifiée s'il le souhaite.

Comment: C'est bien la pratique que je suis, mais cela ouvre la porte à la propagation d'erreurs, car un commentaire est moins visible qu'une réponse.

Comment: @Frank Un commentaire, en particulier s'il est *upvoté*, est parfois plus visible qu'un paragraphe d'une réponse. PS: et pas de remarque sur un éventuel anglicisme qui se serait glissé dans ce commentaire ;-)

Comment: Ne suis-je pas le premier a avoir utilisé _upvoté_ ;-) (on parle beaucoup comme ça ici en Californie...)

Answer (score 2):

La mission du site fait l'objet d'une [définition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480?phase=definition) avant même le lancement d'un *beta*, il y a 2036 jours pour *French Language*. De celle-ci on peut déduire que les réponses ne seraient pas uniquement destinées à une personne qui apprend le français :

> Le site « French Language Stack Exchange » est un site de questions et
>   réponses consacré à la langue française. Il s'adresse aux linguistes,
>   aux enseignants, aux étudiants, et à toute personne qui s'intéresse de
>   près à la langue française (y compris ses variations régionales ou
>   dialectales).
>
> ---
>
> The French Language Stack Exchange site is for linguists, teachers,
>   students, and anyone interested in the finer points of the French
>   language. We welcome questions about French (including regional or
>   dialectal variants) that meet the general [Stack Exchange guidelines](https://french.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).
>
> [ [Aide en ligne du site](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ]

---

Le site explore déjà bien des nuances de la langue : [oral](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral), [régionalismes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r%c3%a9gionalismes), [france](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/france), [belgique](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belgique), [québec](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qu%c3%a9bec), [argot](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/argot), [registre-familier](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registre-familier), [interjections](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interjections), [onomatopées](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onomatop%c3%a9es), [néologismes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/n%c3%a9ologismes), [anglicismes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anglicismes), [néerlandais](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/n%c3%a9erlandais), [ancien-français](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancien-fran%c3%a7ais), [emprunts](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emprunts), [allemand](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allemand), [dialectes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialectes), [ancien-français](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancien-fran%c3%a7ais), [accents-régionaux](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accents-r%c3%a9gionaux), [niveau-de-langue](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/niveau-de-langue), [euphonie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euphonie), [tutoiement](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutoiement), [afrique](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afrique), [suisse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suisse), [verlan](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verlan) et j'en passe, incluant [standard](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard) puisque les thèmes de votre question peuvent intéresser directement le site principal. Les dictionnaires et grammaires eux-même traitent souvent des différents usages, registres, niveaux de langue, régionalismes etc. Ce doit être intéressant.

---

Dans l'[aide](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), on demande qu'un contributeur éprouvant une difficulté identique à celle retrouvée dans une question :

> Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute
>   the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a
>   partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next
>   person has more to go on.

Le concept repose sur la valeur ajoutée par la multitude et la diversité des contenus et des horizons, et non sur l'élaboration d'une réponse parfaite ou unique, à mon avis. Comme on le mentionne ailleurs, il est préférable d'avoir le maximum d'informations, incluant le registre et l'identification des régionalismes et autres particularités, ce que le site [encourage](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) généralement :

> [...] but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or
>   simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller
>   explanations are better.

On encourage l'emploi de *liens* en contexte vers des contenus externes et les extraits pertinents de [citations](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) quand c'est utile à la réponse. On demande d'écrire *du mieux possible* et on rappelle qu'on peut améliorer ses contributions lors de modifications ultérieures. Enfin la mécanique du [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) employée à bon escient (précisions, critique constructive, ajout d'informations de peu d'importance ou éphémères) permet d'obtenir des précisions au besoin.

---

Enfin il faut noter que les acceptions de *cheesy* dont on traitait en [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25094/french-equivalent-for-cheesy) sont marqués *informal/slang* au [dictionnaire](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cheesy?s=t) ; pourquoi imposerait-on aux réponses un standard auquel ne serait pas tenu le terme dans sa langue d'origine ? Et puis les [*chevals*](https://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/actualites/capsules_hebdo/actualites_terminolinguistique/rappel_cheval_20050909.html) ? Pourquoi ne pas poser la question et mettre à l'épreuve ces idées ?

Comment: Les définitions des sites sur Stack Exchange sont ouvertes au changement, et ont plusieurs fois changé, pour préciser tel ou tel point. Qui plus est, on parle encore d'une **beta**, absolument rien n'est coulé dans le béton :) Cela étant dit, certes, la description présente semble ouvrir la porte à tout ça.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Une fonction _edit_ existe mais ce que vous proposez ne serait pas une _précision_ mais un changement de cap à 180 degrés. Un beta de 2036 jours n'est pas qu'un simple beta ; il y a 5000 questions avant la vôtre et, considérant, votre propos m'apparaît légèrement présomptueux, sauf le respect. Personnellement j'ai soif de davantage que de simples généralités pour un public d'apprenants. Je n'accorderai pas mon appui à un dépeçage arbitraire du genre de celui que je pense que vous suggérez. _Tout ça_, c'est la richesse de la langue, pas un _side order d'onion rings_. Merci!

Comment: Je n'ai parlé d'aucun dépeçage, je suis venu demander l'avis de la communauté. J'ignore ce que vous y trouvez de présomptueux. En fait, c'est vous qui présumez de mes intentions. Merci d'avoir partagé votre avis.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Je vous en prie. Je ne présume pas de vos intentions, vous n'avez pas défini ce que constitue _la référence actuelle, acceptée internationalement_, mais avez directement identifié le _langage populaire_ et les _expressions qui dépendent largement de la localisation de la personne qui réponds_ comme des choses à éviter, de l'inscrire à la mission. Je ne dois pas comprendre ce que vous envisagez. Qu'est-ce que ça peut faire de retrouver un truc populaire ou régional et un truc plus régulier à la fois en réponse comme ce fut le cas ? Et _cheesy_, c'est informel etc. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

Je ne pense pas qu'il faille refuser un certain langage, mais qu'il faille bien préciser dans quel registre il s'utilise.

Lorsqu'une personne non francophone demande l'équivalent d'une expression, elle doit aussi préciser le contexte et on se doit de lui répondre par une expression du même contexte. On peut aussi, pour sa culture, lui donner des équivalents dans d'autres contextes, mais ce que la personne cherche avant tout, c'est garder le contexte.

À ma connaissance, "cheesy" est familier en anglais. Imaginez, par exemple, qu'on souhaite traduire une conversation entre adolescents dans laquelle l'un d'eux dit "cheezy". Pensez-vous qu'"à l'eau de rose" soit réaliste ?

Comment: Seule la personne qui pose la question sait si elle accorde plus d'importance au registre ou plus d'importance à la fidélité de la traduction. Je conviens bien sûr que l'idéal est d'avoir les deux. Quand à l'utilisation de l'expression "roman à l'eau de rose" par des adolescents, je ne la trouve pas inconcevable.

Answer (score 1):

Aussi, il faut bien parler des mots que les gens entendront, même s'ils ne sont pas recommandables. Je pense que si l'on précise le registre, c'est bon.

Pour ce qui est de l'évolution de la langue, ce n'est sous le contrôle de personne, en fait, et il est fort probable que, d'une part, les Romains qui nous ont précédés considéreraient notre langue comme "dégénérée", et d'autre, que nous ne reconnaîtrions pas la langue "française" dans 100 ans, ou même 20 ans...

Comment: Effectivement, expliquer ce que les mots que les gens vont entendre veulent dire est une bonne idée. Toutefois, les expressions ne sont pas universelles. Dans le cas des équivalences au mot "cheesy", je n'ai littéralement jamais entendu certaines des suggestions. Est-ce qu'il faut parler de toutes les versions régionales? Comment on décide lesquelles sont assez utilisées? Si quelqu'un habite en France, peut-être vont-ils entendre "gnangnan". S'ils habitent au Québec, probablement qu'ils ne l'entendront jamais de leur vie.

Comment: Par rapport à l'évolution de la langue, je suis assez d'accord, mais ne nous méprenons pas. Je ne crois pas qu'il appartient à une communauté d'internautes de mettre de l'avant telles ou telles versions régionalisées (comme ce qui est recensé sur le site du cnrtl). L'évolution se fera naturellement, et nous devrions essayer de ne pas l'influencer, dans un sens ou l'autre. D'où mon questionnement: ne devrions-nous pas recommander seulement des expressions reconnues internationalement? (si une telle référence existe...)

Comment: Nous ne "recommandons" pas nécessairement. Plutôt, nous éclaircissons, expliquons les possibilités et leurs registres, donnons des examples ... Je me garderai bien pour ma part de recommander quoi que ce soit. Cela serait une pente dangereuse, et surtout, assez subjective.